# Customer login not working in iframe for magento

Tags: magento

I am working on magento website http://20.204.34.13/ i want to load this site into iframe. Site is loading but customer login is not working. Does anyone can suggest solution for this. Below is iframe html.

If iframe is on same domain then it works fine see example http://20.204.34.13/pub/demoscript/iframe_check.html

`

### HTML Iframes

You can also use the CSS height and width properties to specify the size of the iframe:

`

If iframe is on same domain then it works fine see example http://20.204.34.13/pub/demoscript/iframe_check.html

I need session to work in iframe